# How to capture physical barcode scanner's scanned input text inside a screen in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mobile, barcode-scanner

I am working on an application using React Native version `0.68.2`.

I would like to detect a barcode scanning event from a physical scanner hardware available in the mobile itself (it is a handheld scanner).

The application must be able to detect the scanned input ***without*** focusing on any visible `TextInput`.

How to do such task?

Comment: Do you want a scanner like expo app. or you want to attach a connect a device to your mobile phone and then detect the bar code reader

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq The mobile device itself already contains the scanner hardware as part of the product from the factory. It normally scans the barcode and writes whatever it reads to an input field that is currently focused. I just want a solution to be able to capture the scanned text without focusing on any input; so that I can process the data from that event and do other tasks when the barcode is scanned.

Comment: there are multiple solution for this. first you can create a textinput field that is always focused but display is none. the second solution for this is to add some event listener and store the scanned text into a state varaible. if you can share a minimal git repos of your work so i will try to find out some souolution for that.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like there's no window.onkeypress events available like you'd use in a normal webapp. But, could one option be to automatically focus an invisible/transparent/hidden TextInput when no other TextInputs are focused?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
    const invisibleRef = React.useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        invisibleRef.current.focus();
    }, []);

    const focusInvisibleInput = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (invisibleRef.current) {
            invisibleRef.current.focus();
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} onTouchStart={focusInvisibleInput}>
            <TextInput
                ref={invisibleRef}
                autoFocus={true}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoComplete={false}
                style={{ opacity: 0 }}
                onChangeText={(text) => console.log("hidden", text)}
            />

            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
                placeholder="Type something here"
                onChangeText={(text) => console.log("visible", text)}
            />

            <Text>A nice react native app!</Text>

            <TextInput
                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
                placeholder="Type some thing else here!"
                onChangeText={(text) => console.log("visible", text)}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
});
```

And after this, you may want to add a generic input handler that times the speed of the input of the text, to figure out if it's a scan, rather than manual text input. (if you get 20 characters within 50ms, you can be pretty sure it's a scan, right?)

There's probably tons of other ways of doing this way better, but none that I could find right now.

Hope that helps!